# How to see what errors I am getting while app runs without being connected?

Tags: ios, runtime-error, out-of-memory

I am using an external sensor that attaches to the iPhone via the lighting charger therefore I cannot see the logs while I run my app. I want to know what is making my app crash. Is there is a way to get that information? (I am thinking I have a memory error but I want to be sure).

Thanks!

Comment: why not use step through so as you are going through the code put a few breakpoints along the way and step through it.

Comment: @logixologist I just tried that. The problem is that the app crashes almost immediately so the breakpoints didn't really help. Thanks though.

Comment: did you check "~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/" folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use a service like Firebase:

```
https://firebase.google.com/
```

it has crash reporting and you can set your own logs by that

here you can read about crash reporting:

```
https://firebase.google.com/products/crash/
```

Comment: I took a look at firebase, and it seems like it is the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. it has many features that might be interesting for you beside crash reporting